# DDD + Entityframework + Migrations + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, api, ddd, migrations

Olá, tenho uma Solution que estou implementando a arquitetura DDD com Entityframework, migrations e SQL Server! Porém não estou conseguindo realizar a conexão com meu banco de dados local ao realizar o comando do migrations: 'Updata-database'! Acredito que apenas com a Connectionstring inserida na WebConfig da API já consigo fazer essa conexão. É isso mesmo? ou tenho que fazer outra configuração no DDD?

Atualmente minha Connectionstring está da seguinte forma:

```js
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BWSDatabase" 
         connectionString="Server=localhost; 
                           Database=BWSDatabase; 
                           Data Source=DESKTOP-PTI280V;
                           Integrated Security=True;
                           Connect Timeout=30;
                           Encrypt=False;
                           TrustServerCertificate=False;
                           ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
                           MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Desta forma as tabelas são geradas localmente em uma estancia do SLQ Server express no SQL Server Object Explorer, assim como a foto abaixo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando o DDD em camada, que são:
     1- Services (Camada da API)
     2- Application (Camada de Desenvolvimento)
     3- Domain
     4- Infra (Camada aonde fica o migrations)

Estou executando o comando pelo 'Package Manager Console', e apenas é gerado as tabelas, e se rodar de novo o comando apresenta a mensagem de que não tem atualização no migrations

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você está fazendo desenvolvimento multicamadas? se sim, tem como adicionar na pergunta as camadas que está usando e onde fica a camada onde estão as `migrations`?. Você executou o comando pelo `package manager console`?, se sim, tem como adicionar na pergunta a `stack` gerada?

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi uma coisa, em cima você diz que não consegue gerar o banco, em baixo diz que as tabelas são geradas, o problema não me ficou claro :X

Comment: O problema é que as tabelas são geradas no localDb SQL Server Express e não no próprio banco de dados SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string de conexão pode ser mais simples do que essa, claro que, dependendo do que deseja, ainda vale a pena passar algumas definições por ela. Porém tem que ter motivo.

Supondo que tenha criado uma instância do `SQLEXPRESS` você pode usar a própria autenticação do `windows` para se conectar a base de dados, sua string ficaria assim:

```
<add name="MeuSistemaDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BANCO_DE_DADOS;Integrated Security=true providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Um fato que também pode estar ocorrendo no seu caso é o seu contexto não chamar a string de conexão, por padrão ele irá procurar a string de conexão que tenha o mesmo nome, ou seja, se seu contexto chama `MeuSistemaDbContext`, ele irá procurar a `string de conexão` com esse nome. Caso ela tenha um nome diferente você deverá passar esse nome para o construtor no seu `DbContext`

Agora, caso você tenha 1 usuário e senha para acessar a base, você pode usar a seguinte `string de conexão`

```
<add name="MeuSistemaDbContext" connectionString="Database=BANCO_DE_DADOS; Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; User Id=USUARIO; Password=SENHA" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```